# WPF ugly event dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that gets data from a web-server.

It contains two Views

- `LeftView`
- `RightView`

three Models

- `LeftModel`
- `RightModel`
- `CentralModel`

and two ViewModels

- `LeftViewModel`
- `RightViewModel`

I will show only `LeftView`, `LeftViewModel`, `LeftModel`, and `CentralModel` (too much code). You can find the entire project [here](https://A191919@bitbucket.org/A191919/wpfapplication139.git).

I guess the main problem is that the `UpdateCollection()` have high coupling with `public ObservableCollection<SomeTypeA> Items {get; set;}`.

Therefore I have the feeling that I cannot place `UpdateCollection()` in `CentralModel`.

I think it will be better if `UpdateCollection()` will be in `CentralModel`

Work logic is very simple, incoming message from web server add into `public Dictionary<string, Action<MessageReceivedEventArgs>> Handle { get; set; }`

```
        public void Message(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dresult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA>>(e.Message);
        if (Handle.ContainsKey(dresult.Keys.ToList()[0]))
        {
            Handle[dresult.Keys.ToList()[0]](e);
        }
    }
```

, if dictionary contains key, it firing event in model

```
CentralModel.Instance.Handle.Add("central_office", (m) =>
        {
            var dresult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA>>(m.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Message.ToString());
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,SomeTypeA> item in dresult)
            {
                if (!Items.Any(key=>key.ID==dresult["central_office"].ID))
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => Items.Add(item.Value)));
                }
                foreach (SomeTypeA subitem in Items)
                {
                    subitem.ID = item.Value.ID;
                    subitem.Name = item.Value.Name;
                    subitem.Value = item.Value.Value;
                    subitem.Work = item.Value.Work;
                    subitem.Department = item.Value.Department;
                }
            }
        });
```

**ServerClass.cs**

```
namespace Server
{
class ServerClass
{
    private WebSocketServer appServer;

    public void Setup()
    {
        appServer = new WebSocketServer();

        if (!appServer.Setup(2012)) //Setup with listening port
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to setup!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        appServer.NewMessageReceived += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession, string>(appServer_NewMessageReceived);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (!appServer.Start())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to start!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The server started successfully! Press any key to see application options.");

        SomeTypeA FirstWorker = new SomeTypeA()
        {
            Department = "Finance",
            ID = "0",
            Name = "John",
            Work = "calculate money"
        };
        SomeTypeB SecondWorker = new SomeTypeB()
        {
            ID = "1",
            Name = "Nick",
            Work = "clean toilet"
        };

        while (true)
        {
            FirstWorker.value += 1;
            SecondWorker.value += 5;
            Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA> Element1 = new Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA>();
            Element1.Add("central_office", FirstWorker);
            Dictionary<string, SomeTypeB> Element2 = new Dictionary<string, SomeTypeB>();
            Element2.Add("back_office", SecondWorker);
            string message1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Element1);
            string message2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Element2);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            foreach (WebSocketSession session in appServer.GetAllSessions())
            {
                session.Send(message1);
                session.Send(message2);
            }
        }
    }

    private void appServer_NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client said: " + message);
        session.Send("Server responded back: " + message);
    }
}
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
namespace Server
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServerClass myServer = new ServerClass();
        myServer.Setup();
        myServer.Start();
    }
}
}
```

**LeftView.cs**

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LM.Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Work}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Value}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding ID}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="{Binding Department}"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**LeftViewModel.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication139.ViewModels
{
public class LeftViewModel
{
    public LeftModel LM { get; set; }
    public LeftViewModel()
    {
        LM = new LeftModel();
    }
}
}
```

**LeftModel.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication139.Models
{
public class LeftModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeTypeA> Items {get; set;}
    public LeftModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<SomeTypeA>();
        CentralModel.Instance.Setup("ws://127.0.0.1:2012", "basic", WebSocketVersion.Rfc6455);
        CentralModel.Instance.Start();
        UpdateCollection();
    }

    public void UpdateCollection()
    {
        CentralModel.Instance.Handle.Add("central_office", (m) =>
        {
            var dresult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA>>(m.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Message.ToString());
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,SomeTypeA> item in dresult)
            {
                if (!Items.Any(key=>key.ID==dresult["central_office"].ID))
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => Items.Add(item.Value)));
                }
                foreach (SomeTypeA subitem in Items)
                {
                    subitem.ID = item.Value.ID;
                    subitem.Name = item.Value.Name;
                    subitem.Value = item.Value.Value;
                    subitem.Work = item.Value.Work;
                    subitem.Department = item.Value.Department;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

**CentralModel.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication139.Models
{
public class CentralModel
{
    private WebSocket websocketClient;

    private string url;
    private string protocol;
    private WebSocketVersion version;

    private static CentralModel instance;

    public Dictionary<string, Action<MessageReceivedEventArgs>> Handle { get; set; }
    private CentralModel()
    {
        Handle = new Dictionary<string, Action<MessageReceivedEventArgs>>();
    }
    public void Setup(string url, string protocol, WebSocketVersion version)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.protocol = protocol;
        this.version = WebSocketVersion.Rfc6455;

        websocketClient = new WebSocket(this.url, this.protocol, this.version);
        websocketClient.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(CentralModel.Instance.Message);
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        websocketClient.Open();
    }
    public static CentralModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new CentralModel();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    public void Message(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dresult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA>>(e.Message);
        if (Handle.ContainsKey(dresult.Keys.ToList()[0]))
        {
            Handle[dresult.Keys.ToList()[0]](e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

SomeTypeA and SomeTypeB using for json serealization of two types of messages.

**SomeTypeA.cs**

```
public class SomeTypeA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Work { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

**SomeTypeB.cs**

```
public class SomeTypeB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Work { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should consider giving your classes meaningful names. Otherwise it's hard to give you a meaningful feedback. How some1 is supposed to figure out what your code does, when you have classes such as `SomeClassB` all over your code and no explanations whatsoever.

Comment: First sentenc describe what is going on "I have a wpf application that gets data from webserver." I agree with you that maybe SomeTypeA and SomeTypeB it is not good. But that is not main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from obvious issues with naming, a few other things caught my eye.

1. Binding wpf view to objects, which do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, causes memory leaks. You should always implement it on your view model, even if you don't actually use the event. Same goes for collections and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.
2. `ObservableCollection` should be used on view model level according to MVVM pattern.
3. Singleton is an anti-pattern in most cases (your case included). You shouldn't use it. Instead you should implement some service (which will act as "model" in MVVM terms) with easy-to-use interface and inject it into your viewmodel. For example:

   ```
   interface IEployeeService
   {
       //here you access your server, fetch needed data, etc.
       //your view model should not care about implementation details
       IList<Employee> GetAll();
   }

   public class LeftViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public LeftViewModel(IEployeeService service)
       {
           _service = service;
       }

       public ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> Items { get; set; }

       public void UpdateCollection()
       {
           var result = _service.GetAll();
           //update Items
           //....
       }

       private readonly IEployeeService _service;
   }
   ```
4. `Dispatcher.Invoke` is slow and often causes deadlocks in multithreaded environment. You should use `BeginInvoke` instead.
5. I failed to understand the logic behind your "event dictionary", so I can't really comment on that. But it feels like it should not be allowed to exist :)